# Jersey Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, jersey, startup

How it's possible to load something at the start of the system? I`m not have a "main" where my program starts !?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a singleton object defined in [`Application#getSingletons()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getSingletons%28%29).

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
        Foo foo = /* init foo somehow */;
        set.add(foo);
        return set;
    }
}
```

From [RESTful Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=_jQtCL5_vAcC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22restful%20java%22&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false) (if you have the book, see p.142):

> The `getSingletons()` method returns a list of preallocated JAX-RS web services and `@Provider`-annotated classes. You, as the application programmer, are responsible for creating these objects. The JAX-RS runtime will iterate through the list of objects and register them internally. When these objects are registered, JAX-RS will also inject values for `@Context` annotated fields and setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

generally, the jersey is built by maven. So, when you execute the maven command, there's a initialized project generated.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.4.1
```

More info please see:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could write a class that implements ServletContextListener.

```
    public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
            //stuff that happens when server is started
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
            //stuff that happens when server is turned off
        }
    }
```

Then you would just add this to your web.xml file as child to the web-app element.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mypackage.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```